# IntegrityError : NOT NULL constraint failed with OneToOneFields

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms

I'm trying to make some forms with django.

I made some Models :

```
class Identity(models.Model):
    [...]

class Move(models.Model):
    identity = models.OneToOneField(Identity, blank=True)
    [...]
```

And a view :

```
def firstform(request):
    forms = {}
    if request.method == "POST":
        forms["move_form"] = MoveForm(request.POST)
        forms["identity_form"] = IdentityForm(request.POST)
        if all((forms["move_form"].is_valid(),
                forms["identity_form"].is_valid())):
            forms["identity_form"].save()
            forms["move_form"].identity = forms["identity_form"]
            forms["move_form"].save()
            return HttpResponse("OK")
    else:
        forms["move_form"] = MoveForm()
        forms["identity_form"] = IdentityForm()
    return (render(request, "main/devis.html", forms))
```

But when I try to submit my form I get a `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: main_move.identity_id`.

How could I solve this?

Comment: I don't see `main_move` anywhere in your code--perhaps you can post your updated code that gives you this error?

Comment: @gorus main is the name of the app, move the name of the class, and estimate_query the name of a field : I mistook two fields, my bad! The problem wasn't about the identity field. **EDIT** Nevermind, I corrected the problem about estimate_query and I got the same error with identity. (I edited the post)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, I only had to replace `blank=True` with `null=True` in my `Move` class. My bad : it was pretty stupid.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to assign the identity instance explicitly, instead of the saved form:

```
identity = forms["identity_form"].save()
forms["move_form"].identity = identity
forms["move_form"].save()
```

Comment: It wasn't this, both notations work but this one seems useful to me (less code).

Answer (score 0):

When you call the form's `save()` method, it returns the instance. You should assign the `identity` to the `move` instance, not the move form.

Secondly, use `commit=False` when saving the move form. This means the instance isn't saved to the database, so you don't get the `IntegrityError`. This way, you can keep `null=False` in your model if you want all identities to have a move.

```
    forms["move_form"] = MoveForm(request.POST)
    forms["identity_form"] = IdentityForm(request.POST)
    if all((forms["move_form"].is_valid(),
            forms["identity_form"].is_valid())):
        move = forms["move_form"].save(commit=False)
        identity = forms["identity_form"].save()
        move.identity = identity
        move.save()
        # It's usually a good idea to redirect here rather than
        # returning a response
        return HttpResponse("OK")
```